# The definition of $\psi_{0}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Very short question here, looking at the prime number theorem and the explicit formula for $\psi(x)$. In it the definition of $\psi_{0}$ is explained as "$\psi(x)$ when $x$ is not a prime power, and $\psi(x)-\frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ when it is". Is there any reason the distinction between the two cases were made? As far as I can tell $\psi_{0}(x)=\psi(x)-\frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ for all $x$, so that the cases are treated differently confuses me.

Comment: Typically $\Lambda(x)$ is only defined for positive integers $x$, so $\psi(x) - \frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ isn't a well-formed expression unless $x$ is a positive integer. If you extend $\Lambda$ to real $x$ (setting $\Lambda(x) = 0$ if $x$ isn't a positive integer), then indeed $\psi_0(x) = \psi(x) - \frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ is well-formed and correct for all real $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\psi_o(x)=\psi(x)-\frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ is true for all positive integers $x>1$, but when $x>1$ is a positive integer which is not a prime power $\Lambda(x)=0$ so this simplifies to $\psi_o(x)=\psi(x)$. Whereas the $\psi(x)$ function is a sum of generalized functions (sum of distributions), the function $\psi_0(x)$ is a continuous function and when $\psi(x)$ takes a step at a prime power $x$ the $\psi_0(x)$ function converges to $\psi_o(x)=\psi(x)-\frac{1}{2}\Lambda(x)$ consistent with the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) half-maximum convention.